# How to log ASP.NET Web API request body into a Application Insights failure?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I'm logging my unhandled exceptions in an ExceptionLogger using the TelemetryClient to Application Insights on Azure.

```
public class GlobalExceptionLogger : ExceptionLogger
{
    public override void Log(ExceptionLoggerContext context)
    {
        if (context != null && context.Exception != null)
        {
              //For simplification a new TelemetryClient instance
              //This is not recommended!
              new TelemetryClient().TrackException(context.Exception);
        }
        base.Log(context);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to log the Web API Request body so I can view it on the Application Insights dashboard on the Azure Portal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create ExceptionTelemetry instance and add custom properties. Then call general Track method.

```
var telemetry = new ExceptionTelemetry(context.Exception);
telemetry.Properties.Add("name", "value");
new TelemetryClient().Track(telemetry);
```

Comment: there are also version of the `Track*` methods that take dictionaries, so you can do something like `new TelemetryClient().TrackException(e, new Dictionary<string,string> { { "key", "value" }, { "key2", "value2" } } );`